# Windows equivalent command for Octal Dump(OD)?

Tags: windows, linux

What is windows equivalent command for od

In Linux - echo xxxxx | POST url | od -xv

So what's the equivalent command in windows?

Comment: http://www.richpasco.org/utilities/hexdump.html

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/468456/how-can-i-view-the-binary-contents-of-a-file-natively-in-windows-7-is-it-possi

Comment: And here's the *correct* answer (IMHO) from Oliver's SU post above:
https://superuser.com/a/1247756/320756 which is to use Powershell's `Format-Hex`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`od` is part of [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), available via GnuWin32.

Comment: Given that most (if not all?) modern Windows boxes have Powershell, the more appropriate answers are in the comments on the original post/question, instead of installing Linux tools (which is not a bad idea anyway, althought these days using WSL and a true Linux might be easier.